# Is there a standard GZIP decompressor filter available? Or do I have to write my own?

Tags: java, servlets, gzip, servlet-filters, gzipoutputstream

I have a SOAP server implemented using Spring-ws. Now the clients for the servers are are going to send the requests in gzip encoding. I need to make my server compatible for that. I googled but all I found some standard library which provide the compressor filter not the decompressor. Is there any standard filter available or do I have to write my own

Comment: do you have any load balancer or proxy server in front of your SOAP server?

Comment: No, and we can't use those. I have to handle it in application level :(

Comment: Then need to write by yourself but you will find sample code easily